# скажите, как можно узнать дату установки драйвера флешки на компьютер

Tags: windows, драйвер, железо, реестр

когда купленная флешка была вставлена в комьютер(гнездо)
началось установка её драйвера на комьютер.

скажите, как можно узнать дату установки драйвера флешки на компьютер
дата\время\год

Comment: Записать дату установки на листик:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дополню.

1. Если необходимая информация о дате отсутствует в файлах, перечисленных Сергеем. То можно выгрузить информацию о создании ветви реестра, связанной с драйвером устройства. Средствами regedit: экспортировать нужную ветвь в txt-файл. В файле будет указано время модификации параметров.
2. Ну и, конечно же, есть отличная бесплатная утилита [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html), с помощью которой можно ещё и автоматизировать процесс сбора информации.

Comment: спасибо за программу!

Answer (score 3):

Если это Windows Vista или более поздние, то информацию найдете в `C:\Windows\INF\setupapi.dev.log`

Для Windows XP можно в папке `C:\Windows\INF` поискать `.inf` файл установленного драйвера, затем проверить время создания `.pnf` файла с тем же именем.

Comment: Большое Вам человеческое спасибо!